# The comparison of two Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

Tags: harmonic-analysis

The uncentered Hardy-Littlewood maximal function of $f$ is
$$\tilde{M}(f)=\sup\limits_{|y-x|<\delta}\frac{1}{|B(y,\delta)|}\int_{B(y,\delta)}|f|$$
If we denote the original Hardy-Littlewood maximal function as $M(f)$. In Grafakos's book, he states that $\tilde{M}(f)\leq 2^nM(f)$. I don't know how to prove this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $|y-x|<\delta$ and $|z-y|<\delta$ then $|z-x|<2\delta$. Therefore $B(y,\delta)\subset B(x,2\delta)$, hence
$$ \frac{1}{|B(y,\delta)|}\int_{B(y,\delta)}|f|\leq \frac{|B(x,2\delta)|}{|B(y,\delta)|}\frac{1}{|B(x,2\delta)|}\int_{B(x,2\delta)}|f|$$
$$ =2^n\frac{1}{|B(x,2\delta)|}\int_{B(x,2\delta)}|f|\leq 2^nMf(x)$$
and the result follows by taking the supremum.

Comment: How is $\frac{|B(x,2\delta)|}{|B(y,\delta)|} = 2^n$ ?

Comment: @gaufler  The [volume of an $n$-dim ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#The_volume) of radius $r$ is proportional to $r^n$, so doubling $r$ ...